# exclude specific fields in flask-admin's create/edit forms

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have some fields in my models which I specifically want to exclude from my `ModelView`.

Reference https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/, I attempted to exclude those specific fields using `form_exclude_columns`, e.g.

```
class UserView(ModelView):

    form_exclude_columns = ('created', 'modified')
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

How can I easily exclude these two fields in my `create` and `edit` ModelView pages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The attribute should be named `form_excluded_columns`. You forgot the 'd'.

```
class UserView(ModelView):

    form_excluded_columns = ('created', 'modified')
```

Comment: LOL!! I must be blind...

THANKS!